# How to get stack trace string without raising exception in python?

Tags: python, stack-trace

`traceback.format_exc()`

can get it with raising an exception.

`traceback.print_stack()`

prints the stack without an exception needed, but it does not return a string.

There doesn't seem to be a way to get the stack trace string without raising an exception in python?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's `traceback.extract_stack()` if you want convenient access to module and function names and line numbers, or `''.join(traceback.format_stack())` if you just want a string that looks like the `traceback.print_stack()` output.

Comment: Notice that even with `''.join` you will get a multiline string, since the elements of `format_stack()` contain `\n`s.

Comment: The stacktrace I got in my app with `format_stack` had many layers I wasn't interested in and would never get picked up by the normal debugger.  `format_exception` had less noise for me in a Flask app and looked closer to the normal stack dumps in my running output: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62952273/how-to-catch-python-exception-and-save-traceback-text-as-string

Answer (score 4):

How about [traceback.format_stack?](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_stack)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [inspect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) module.  In particular, inspect. currentframe() -- but the whole module is there for the purpose of looking at the state of your program at a given time.

Some useful inspect tricks [here.](http://ginstrom.com/scribbles/2007/10/24/python-introspection-with-the-inspect-module/)

Answer (score 1):

Also try the "py-spy" module, which can connect to a python process and get the instantaneous stack dump.